# I just started using Elementor for WordPress and I want to know how I can create a fade in/fade out underline effect for a heading

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

Here is a website that has the effect I am looking for: https://wehaulmo.com/

The "Reach Out Today" link in each section is what I am specifically referring to here.

I am not certain if this is custom css that was used or if there is actually a widget that helps create this effect in Elementor. I can create this effect just using an index.html and a style.css with no problem, but again, I am trying to understand how to get this done in Elementor for WordPress sites.

I must be missing something here because this effect is quite standard and I cannot for the life of me find the widget/element in Elementor that can create this underline effect.

If anyone out there is an Elementor guru, your help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anytime you need to do something front-ended in an Elementor page that can't be done with widgets, you can use a few ways to actually throw some css (and even JS) in there.

---

**1 - HTML WIDGET (Works without Elementor Pro)**

Insert the HTML widget where you would need your element to be. The HTML widget offers a textarea in the 'content' tab. In this text area, you can write HTML code, but you can also add CSS by using a `<style></style>` tag. Like this for example:

```
<p class="demo">Hello!</p>

<style>
.demo{
    color: blue;
}
</style>
```

You can even add a `<script></script>` tag if you need some Javascript.

Also, every Elementor frontend widget has an 'advanced' tab in which you can find the 'advanced' *section* (First section of 'advanced' tab). In that section there are two fields labelled 'CSS ID' and 'CSS Class', which allow you to add an ID and/or a class to that element. You can then refer to that class or ID in your CSS and Javascript with a DOM.

---

**2 - Custom CSS (Pro Only)**

Every (almost every) widget in Elementor has a 'custom CSS' section under its 'advanced' tab. Keep in mind that you need Elementor ***Pro*** to access this section. You can write all the CSS you need in that section.

Also, in that text area, you can refer to the element you are editing without needing its classname or id, simply by using 'selector' as such:

```
selector{
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

> Use "selector" to target wrapper element

---

**3 - Plugins**

There is a variety of plugins that are made specifically to add code to Elementor and other editors, with shortcodes or through other methods.

---

---

**In your case**

In your case, using the first way I described (HTML WIDGET), you would need to write something along the lines of this in your HTML Widget's textarea :

```
<a href="#" class="demo">REACH OUT TODAY</a>
<style>
.demo {
  color: #f89c27;
  font-size: 24px;
  letter-spacing: 0.20em;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.demo:hover{
    color: #f89c27;
}

.demo:after {    
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
  bottom: 0;
  content: "";
position: absolute;
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  left: 50%;
  background: #f89c27;
  transition: width 0.3s ease 0s, left 0.3s ease 0s;
  width: 0;
}

.demo:hover:after {
  left: 0;
  width: 100%; 

}
</style>
```

Comment: I saw that there is an html widget and was considering that, but when I inspected the element on the website, it shows that the link is using an Elementor heading instead. Anyway, I will give this a shot. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, I inspected it too. However, as I mentioned, you can give a class or id to an element under its advanced tab. I'm guessing that is what was done, and then the css was added from the custom CSS (Pro only) section. You could probably give a heading a class and then have an html widget containing only CSS to have the same effect if you don't have pro. I hope you find a way to do it that suits you.

Comment: I have pro temporarily. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Sweet! I took care of it! Thanks again man. I just needed to make an Elementor heading, give it a CSS Class ID of "underline", then simply add the custom CSS to the Advanced tab like you said and it was pretty easy peasy.

Comment: Glad I could help man! I find the custom CSS tab very useful if you have pro. Too bad there isn't a javascript equivalent. Anyway, since you mentionned that you just started using Elmentor, don't hesitate to post any other Elementor related questions, I browse the elementor tag almost daily. ;-)

Comment: I'm going to post one more right now as a matter of fact - LOL. Thanks brother.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Shiverz for pointing me in the right direction here, it helped me out greatly. Thanks again man.

Here is the HTML and CSS code that worked for me:

```css
/*** Styling Underline Hyperlink ***/

/* Creating Underline */
.underline.elementor-widget-heading .elementor-heading-title>a {
    position: relative;
}

.underline.elementor-widget-heading .elementor-heading-title>a:after {
    content: '';
    width: 0%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: #FAC074;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -10px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translatex(-50%);
    -webkit-transition: width .4s;
    transition: width .4s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

.underline.elementor-widget-heading .elementor-heading-title>a:hover:after {
    width: 90%;
    -webkit-transition: width .4s;
    transition: width .4s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}

/** Creating Arrow **/
.underline.elementor-widget-heading .elementor-heading-title>a:before {
    content: url(http://ronratzlaff.wpengine.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/icon-arrow-right.svg);
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    right: -12px;
}
```

```html
<div class="elementor-element elementor-element-c3ae88a underline elementor-widget elementor-widget-heading" data-id="c3ae88a" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="heading.default">
    <div class="elementor-widget-container">
        <div class="elementor-heading-title elementor-size-default"><a href="#request">Reach Out Today</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```